# 2 mysql queries at once

Tags: mysql, subquery, union

I have a table like this one..

```
[id][Col1][Col2][id_duplicated]
 10  abc1  defg  NULL
 12  text  text  NULL
 50  abc2  text  NULL
 90  NULL  NULL  10    
 500 NULL  NULL  10 
 620 NULL  NULL  50
 700 text  text  NULL
```

Id_duplicated is a value that marks that is a copy from the row 'id' on the same table.. if i select id 620 will display all values from id 50

**The problem:**

```
select id,col1 from table where col1 is like '%abc%'
```

Only will show the row **id=10** and **id=50** but also i need to display if there's any copies of those id's

i imagine i need a subquery that first find if there's any '%abc%' and then a second one to check if there's any copy on id_duplicated equal to 10 and 50 and etc etc....

So in conclusion i need one query that display this result

```
[id][Col1][Col2][id_duplicated]
 10  abc1  defg  NULL
 50  abc2  text  NULL
 90  NULL  NULL  10    
 500 NULL  NULL  10 
 620 NULL  NULL  50
```

Sorry my english

Comment: While there's probably a use case I'm missing here, but why store duplicates at all? If you are doing this in an attempt to save some sort of space by storing nulls instead of values all you've done is offload complexity (and time) onto your queries. I would consider reorganizing your data and make some hard decisions about why you are storing things this way.

One of the answers below may indeed work, put the keyword EXPLAIN infront of the query and see just how messy MySQL goes about fetching your results.

Comment: Ok.. imagine you have a video in vhs.. you create a new entry.. ej. id=10 then you make a copy id=90(dvd) and then another copy from mp4 (id=500) that contains the same description that the original one.. same program, same everything... instead of have many copies of the same media, i just keep one.. the others are just linked to the master media and you can track what was the first media or format.. to put an example..

Comment: Frankly storage is much cheaper than computation time, but as long as you've thought it though I'm game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want additional rows you can use union and a select looking for the id of the result into the id_duplicated:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad817/8

```
select id,col1, col2, id_duplicated 
    from table 
    where col1 like '%abc%'
UNION 
select id, col1, col2, id_duplicated 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id_duplicated IN (select id from table where col1 like '%abc%')
```